# Sheets: how to return NULL value in IF formula that looks up date value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty sure this is a simple formula. I'm in Google Sheets and I want to find the latest date for a value in one sheet based on the value found in another sheet, or return a null value (blank) if there i no match. Here's what I have now:

```
=arrayformula(Max(IF(B285='2014 Donations Log'!F:F,'2014 Donations Log'!A:A)))
```

BUT. I want the cell to be BLANK if there is no corresponding value in 2014 Donations Log. If I add anything to the IF test, (such as ,"") then it returns a bogus date value that is misleading.

The column is formatted for date.

I need this as a formula.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is not about programming as defined in the help center, perhaps it belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets.

Comment: Mogasdad: Although its pushing the boundary a little, modern spreadsheets are turring complete pure functional "languages" of sorts (The VBA in excel is definately *not* functional, but the formula definition syntax in the cells is).

Answer (score 8):

The solution to this is to refer to some known null column. You can even define that as a name range with a name `NULL` and then you can refer to `NULL` in your formulas. Alternative trick that may be applicable is that if your `IF` formula happens to be checking `ISBLANK` of some field and you e.g. want to only do something if some other field has a value.. well then you obviously have a guaranteed to be `NULL` field conveniently at your hands whenever it is "blank".

Answer (score 0):

To allow for the possibility that the maximum value is indeed `0` (rather than that there is no value):

```
=ArrayFormula(if(iserror(match(B285,'2014 Donations Log'!F:F,0)),"",Max(IF(B285='2014 Donations Log'!F:F,'2014 Donations Log'!A:A))))
```